# JQUERY to change text of div based on time different between SQL timestamp field and NOW()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a script below to pull some data from sql:

```
<?php
  require 'admin-db.php';

  // Define and perform the SQL query
  $sql = "SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `status_time` "
       . "FROM `staffs` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
  $result = $DB_CON->query($sql);

  // If the SQL query is succesfully performed ($result not false)
  if($result !== false) {
    $data_row = '<table class="table table-striped tablesorter">'
              . '<thead>'
                . '<tr>'
                . '<th>ID</th>'
                . '<th>Fist Name</th>'
                . '<th>Last Name</th>'
                . '<th>Status Time</th>'
                . '</tr>'
              . '<tbody>';

    foreach($result as $row) {
      $data_row .=  '<tr>'
                  . '<td scope="row" class="text-center">'.$row['id'].'</td>'
   . '<td>' .$row['first_name'].'</td>'
   . '<td>' .$row['last_name'].'</td>'
   . '<td><div class="status">' .$row['status_time']. '</div><span class="fa fa-times-circle"></span></td>'; 
    }
  }
  $data_row .=  '</tbody>' 
              . '</table>';
  echo $data_row;
```

How would I change my script (see below) to compare between the $row['status_time'] and NOW() to indicate if the time different is more than 30 seconds it return 0 and if less than 30 seconds it return a 1 as text in the div class="status"?

```
<script>
    $('.status:contains(">30 seconds") = $this.text(0) else $this.text(1);
</script>
```

Comment: If you tell me which format status_time return, I can implement this time into my script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be what are you looking for.

```
// foreach tr row
$.each($('tr .status'), function(i, v) {
  // get seconds from date
  var seconds = (Date.now() - Date.parse($(v).text()))/1000;
  if(seconds) {
    (seconds < 30) ? $(this).text('1') : $(this).text('0');
  }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/prgd2vtn/2/)

Comment: Cool! Thanks daremacchine. Your code works if the $row['status_time'] under the foreach loop in my php script return in seconds. However, the $row['status_time'] return the time in this format: "2017-05-07 18:36:22". I guess in order to make your code works we need to change the php script to make $row['status_time'] to return the time difference (in seconds) between "2017-05-07 18:36:22" in this context and the time NOW(). I've tried: . '<td><div class="status">' NOW() - .$row['status_time']. '</div><span class="fa fa-times-circle"></span></td>'; but it returns 2017 which is the year.

Comment: @MasterJoe in php time diff you need to make Date object from your data and then you can use date->diff(time()) or convert date with strtotime function and subtract from now

Comment: I have tried your suggestion using date_diff but somehow I got all sort of error. I believe the error rested in the string format where the two time period are not the same. I got all sort of error when messing around with this. If I declare $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), how do I determine the difference in seconds? I tried date_diff($now, $row['status_time'])) but it didn't work. My sql field 'status_time' is in datetime format.

Comment: So I try (strtotime($now) - strtotime($row['status_time'])) where $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") and I got a return 14401. How do I convert 14401 to second?

Comment: It seems that 14400 are in seconds, but the huge difference is caused by timezone bug. TIMESTAMP recorded the time in EST while datetime recorded the time in UTC. I don't know why it did that. This php datetime crap is so buggy and there a godzillion way to do things which making it even more confusion for novice. It's like dining at an unknown restaurant and there's a zillion items on the menu with a bunch of symbols in Greek.

Comment: It's correct to say that for timestamp, php records it with the Windows time and while datetime is recorded based on the timezone set in php.ini?

Comment: the best practice is have a timestamp in utc and convert date in the front application. Look how UTC in javascript work and then change it in the script above and calculate correct seconds.

Comment: Agreed! BTW, I would prefer to do the math to calculate the time difference via php. So I've this math worked out as:(strtotime($now) - strtotime($row['status_time'])) in the php for the class 'status' so the time difference is already determined let say 10. How would I change your code to take out the math var seconds = (Date.now() - Date.parse($(v).text()))/1000 and let javascript read the text in this case 10 and change to 1 if it's less than 30 and 0 if it's more than 30?

Comment: sorry but if i understand it was my first solution right? https://jsfiddle.net/prgd2vtn